# Change the column header caption in a WinForm DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

How to change the row name with option button?

If option button export selected:

```
Private sub optexport_click()
    txtimport = "I"
    fgcargo.textmatrix(0,2) = "bl number"
    fgcargo.textmatrix(0,4) = "date"
 end sub
```

If option button import selected:

```
Private sub optimport_click()
    txtimport = "E"
    fgcargo.textmatrix(0,2) = "so number"
    fgcargo.textmatrix(0,4) = "date"
 end sub
```

Comment: Is that VB6 or VB.NET - looks suspiciously like VB6. What control is fgcargo (I can guess, but its been a while since I did VB6). What is or isn't working?

Comment: that code in VB6. how i do it in VB.NET? fgcargo is a dataviewgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GridView will take it's column names from the data source.
This means that if you have a column named "bl_number" in the database, the column in the GridView will name the column "bl_number".

You could try something like the following:

```
fcargo.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Text = "bl number"
fcargo.HeaderRow.Cells(4).Text = "date"
```

Where `Cells(ByVal index As Integer)` is the index of the column in the GridView (0 based).

Hope this helps.

**NOTE:** This will not work with a Windows Forms DataGridView control.
For a Windows Forms DataGridView, go into it's columns collection. You can change the header text for each column there.
In code, you could try the following:

```
fcargo.Columns(2).Name = "bl number"
fcargo.Columns(4).Name = "date"
```

Good luck!

Comment: already try it. the result was 'HeaderRow' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'. Is ".text" possible?

Comment: @PetersonAgas see the note on the answer. The code I posted there is for a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` control.
You're working with a `Windows.Forms.DataGridView` control.
Refresh the page and see new code added to my answer.